# AutoHotKey: #IfWinActive not working

Tags: autohotkey

So I was making a `AFK` stopper with `AHK` but I need it to only run in one program so I used `#If WinActive` but to no avail.

```
#If WinActive("ahk_class WINDOWSCLIENT")
while( 1 = 1 ) {
    Send, {W down}
    sleep 240
    Send, {W up}
    sleep 240
    Send, {A down}
    sleep 240
    Send, {A up}
    sleep 240
    Send, {S down}
    sleep 240
    Send, {S up}
    sleep 240
    Send, {D down}
    sleep 240
    Send, {D up}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **[#IfWin directives](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm)** are only for creating context-sensitive hotkeys and hotstrings. 
Try using a loop or SetTimer with **[IfWinActive](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActive.htm)**:

```
Loop 
{
    If WinActive("ahk_class WINDOWSCLIENT")
    {
        while( 1 = 1 ) 
        {
            ; do something
        }
    }
}
```